# What should I do first? Decrypt or Decompress? Python

Tags: python, encryption, des, gzip

I'm trying to decrypt Bloomberg data files that I know are DES encrypted.

`FileName = 'comdty_option_namr.out.gz.enc'`

What is the right order to do things: Open the file and decompress and then decrypt or vice-versa?

Comment: The extension says it is zipped then encoded so do it in reverse order

Comment: FWIW, the sensible order to do this sort of thing is to compress before encrypting, to maximize the entropy of the data supplied to the encryptor. So to reverse the process you decrypt and then decompress.

Comment: And if your encrypted data has enough entropy to be worth compressing with `gzip`, it's probably not encrypted very well…

Comment: I have the code you need in Java and C#. If you still need it send a message here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on the way the file was transformed, and there are two possible ways (in your case is #1):

1. first create the zip, then encrypt the zip
2. first encrypt the file, then zip it

The extension of the file tells you the order of operations, by reading them from left to right:

1. `comdty_option_namr.out` is the name of the file
2. the file got `gzipped`, thus getting to `comdty_option_namr.out.gz`
3. after which the `gzip` archive to encrypted, resulting the file `comdty_option_namr.out.gz.enc`

Comment: So they way back is I decryt and then unzip. In this case I would be unzipping decrypted strings? Is that correct?

Comment: @BuckTurgidson no you'd be unzipping a decrypted file.