# Python SFTP Bloomberg Data License - Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, bloomberg

Is anybody aware of a Python solution to sftp into the Bloomberg enterprise service.  We're converting some bloomberg pulling from Mathworks to Python. Historically, I would have done this in Mathworks [like this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/bdl.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) using the bdl function.

```
username = 'xxxxx';
password = 'xxxxxxxx';
hostname = 'dlsftp.bloomberg.com';
portnumber = 30206;
decrypt = 'nAcLeZ';

c = bdl(username,password,hostname,portnumber,decrypt)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I have not seen this either. But [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741887/what-should-i-do-first-decrypt-or-decompress-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398026/pydes-with-bloomberg-data) give me the impression that maybe Mathworks is conveniently combining SFTP and DES decryption into one function/method. If so, then you can possibly use "conventional" SFTP (such as `pysftp`) to retrieve a DES-encrypted file, which you then decrypt as a separate step (using something like `pyDes`). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that may be next best option. I'm going to reach out to Bloomberg and see if there is a way to turn of decrypt, I'm not sure I need it over SFTP anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for anybody that needs SOCKS proxy through Bloomberg, here is what I've done and it works:

After some research, it appears the decrypt is not necessary. This code works, just be sure to include the two files for a test:  ('readme.txt','readme-test.txt') on your bloomberg server using RequestBuilder or WinSCP.

```
# coding: utf-8

import paramiko
import socket
import socks


proxy_details = {'host': "xxx",
             'port': 1080,
             'username': "xxx",
             'password': "xxx"}

auth_credentials = {'host': "sftp.bloomberg.com",
                'username': "dlxxxxxx",
                'password': "xxxxxx"}

s = socks.socksocket()

s.set_proxy(
  proxy_type=socks.SOCKS5,
  addr=proxy_details['host'],
  port=proxy_details['port'],
  username=proxy_details['username'],
  password=proxy_details['password']
)

#setup the SFTP client using the connected socket
s.connect((auth_credentials['host'],22))
transport = paramiko.Transport(s)
transport.connect(username=auth_credentials['username'],
              password=auth_credentials['password'])

# start SFTP Client from SSH transport
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)  #.get_transport() was appended


#will download readme.txt from the remote server, and save as the filename in the second argument
sftp.get('readme.txt','readme-test.txt')

#Test whether transport is authenticated
print (transport.is_authenticated())

# cleanup
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```